# Accessing metadata for Mapper

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, oracle11g, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a Hadoop Map reduce program which takes a text file as input. The metadta about this file is stored in an oracle database. In mapper I want this information- metadata from Oracle table. 
What's the best practice to get this?

**Solution1:**
In map reduce, driver class get details using JDBC connectivity. Store the information in a distributed cache. From mapper, in setup method access it. 
My thoughts: Any other quick solutions?

**Solution 2:**
Access metadata from mapper setup method. 
My thoughts: No. I dont want to do this. DB hit will be very more. Bad coding.

Any other smart solutions???